# Unity 3D: draw line behind game object/record path taken by game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am creating a VR app in Unity3d using Google cardboard and need to know how to record the path taken by the player (they are traversing a maze). Is there a way of drawing the path taken by the user (possibly in the console; not in the actual game and not visible to the user) and saving this path as an image?

I need to save an image or just a line of where the player went in the game so that I can then email this image/data to the player.. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Trail Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html) component? Apparently [you can set the fade time to infinity](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/trail-renderer-0-infinity.155445/), which should let it record the path an object takes for the duration of the game. Afterwards, you can save a screenshot using an orthographic camera to get an image of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the Player's path in `List` as `Vector3`. Then you can use `LineRenderer` to draw the line.change the vertext amount of the LineRenderer to List.Count with `LineRenderer.SetVertexCount` then loop over the List and change the position of the [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) with LineRenderer.[SetPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html)(loopIndex,playersPo[loopIndex]).

```
List<Vector3> playerPos = new List<Vector3>();

//Store players positions somewhere
//playerPos.Add(pPos);
//playerPos.Add(pPos); 
//playerPos.Add(pPos);


Color red = Color.red;
LineRenderer lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
lineRenderer.SetColors(red, red);
lineRenderer.SetWidth(0.2F, 0.2F);

//Change how mant points based on the mount of positions is the List
lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(playerPos.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < playerPos.Count; i++ )
{
    //Change the postion of the lines
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, playerPos[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to draw LineRenderer on a canvas? So that the line moves with the camera and is always tied to the position of main camera?

Comment: @skyguy Yes there is a way. Although it is complicated. This is not your original question. Your question was about player's position and had nothing to do with Canvas. You should create a new question for the Canvas stuff. Also, you should start accepting answers. You have many  questions with no selected answers. If this guide provided away to do what you wanted in your original question, you can simply accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me in the right direction with using LineRenderer on a UI Canvas? Have you done this before?

Comment: I have not done this before but I think it is possible. If you create a new post for it I will do some experiment and see what I can come up with. How you setup your UI matters. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/render-lines-on-top-of-panel-ui-element.287023/

Comment: @skyguy Modified version that works with UI smoothly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OElcWAZGHi0